# Passing script variables as parameters

Tags: javascript, jsp

I've a javascript variable which i need to pass as a parameter to the included file.
Ex:
var var1 = "test";

Now i need to pass this 'var1' to an include file like this

<%@include file="text.jsp?param1=" + var1 %>

Will this work ? Help me out.

Or, is there any other way around without submitting the form, I need to pass this variable data to that included file which is presented in the same jsp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this can't work, because the include will be parsed on the server side, long before the javascript var is available.

Instead, you need to add a request parameter to the page url:

```
<%@include file="text.jsp?param1=${request('someparam')}" %>
```

Comment: I've that script variable data in the same page which I need further in the included file in the request object.

Comment: @Sririam still, it's not there on the server, only on the client. It won't work.

Comment: here, the whole content of file is treated as URL to the file name. Did it work at your side to statically pass parameters to the included file?

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't work. Your JSP is compiled and run server-side, and the Javascript is executed much later on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

JS processed after JSP. Learn how server side and client side code is executed